# Customize Laravel Passport so it can be used with own Models + JWT

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I would like to use JWT with Laravel Passport for my own API but make use of my own tables / models. Information I have found so far only details the default installation / configuration or is incomplete.

I am new to Passport but have already found information on how to skip the Passport migrations by adding "Passport::IgnoreMigrations()" to app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php.

I also found information about "findForPassport" and "validateForPassportPasswordGrant" where I can override where it will get the username / password but there are no complete examples to find anywhere, just bits and pieces.

I can always go for jwt-auth but everywhere I find people telling that Passport is the official way to go and I think it is more future proof to use Passport.

There are lots of examples to find on the internet on how to set up Passport and it all looks very simple but if I do not want to use the the default tables / models then it becomes very difficult to find information.
My API works without authentication and I have done the first parts to add Passport authentication:

```
composer require laravel/passport

Adding the proper service provider
```

Skip the php artisan passport:install otherwise it will try to add data to tables that are not there so I just generate the keys:

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

In my routes/api.php I have added all the routes to the middleware:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
  ...
}
```

I've also changed my config/auth.php:

```
'guards' => [
   'api' => [
      'driver' => 'passport',
      'provider' => 'User',
   ],
],
```

Note that my model is User with table users. Here is a snippet of my migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('userid');                                   /* User ID */
            $table->string('username', 30);                          /* Username */
            $table->string('password', 64);                          /* Password */
            $table->string('firstname', 100);                        /* First name */
            $table->string('lastname', 100);                         /* Last name */
            $table->string('email', 128);                            /* Email address */
            $table->binary('avatar')->nullable(true);                 /* Picture of user */
            $table->string('phone',30);                              /* Phone number */
            $table->unsignedInteger('deptid')->nullable(true);        /* Department ID */
            /* Note that there is a foreign key needed for the department ID but since the order matters in the creation
               of the tables I will create a separate migrations file for the foreign keys */
            $table->string('timezone', 32);                          /* Local timezone of the user */
            $table->boolean('active');                                      /* Is the user active (true) / inactive (false) */
            $table->dateTime('lastlogon')->nullable(true);            /* Last logon date/time */
            $table->unsignedInteger('created_by')->nullable(true);    /* Which user ID created the record */
            $table->unsignedInteger('updated_by')->nullable(true);    /* Which user ID updated the record */
            $table->timestamps();                                                   /* Timestamps - created_at / updated_at */
        });
```

I will have to add a token and an expire date/time but I have no idea how to proceed further.

How can I override the rest to make it working? What I want is to give back a web token (when login is successful) so this can be used for all API requests. Adding the extra code to verify that the web token is still valid for each request should not be that much work.
And all of this without using the default tables that Passport uses.

Comment: IMO laravel passport is meant to provide API access to 3rd party consumers, if you are building a system that has no need for your end users to create their own apps & authenticate against your system similar to what twitter & facebook do ... then it would be an overkill to use passport. just go with something simple like `tymon/jwt-auth`

Comment: Ahmad is right.

Answer (score 2):

For example if you don't want to use 'user' model and want to use any different model to authenticate.
Follow below steps

In defile that model in grade and provider in config/auth.php

```
'guards' =>[
 ......
'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'customer',
     ],
]
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'customer' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Customer::class,
    ],
```

Create a new middleware "CustomerProvider.php" and check the authentication.Define it in app/http/kernal.php

```
 'customerapi' => \App\Http\Middleware\PassportCustomProvider::class,
```

In api.php route

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
  ...
}
```